# Google Analytics HTTP status -1 when sending hit(s) by request GET https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect

Tags: google-analytics

I am implementing Google Analytics. I can send Hit by:

```
[self.tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"Application" action:@"BecomeActive" label:@"WakeUp" value:NULL] build]];
```

Logs are:

```
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestPostUrl:payload:compression:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:167): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:632): Sending hit(s) POST: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:226): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:529): hit(s) Successfully deleted
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:237): 2 hit(s) sent
```

### BUT!!! When I try to send event like:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
@try {
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"XxxxxTableView"];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"[ERROR] in Automatic screen tracking: %@", exception.description);
}
```

I got following:

```
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:195): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:632): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?av=3.5&cid=e4b9472c-bb43-48f8-8a99-b58a918cdfa9&tid=UA-47572144-2&a=1081489894&dm=iPhone7%2C2&cd=XxxxxTableView&t=screenview&aid=com.yyyyyyy.appName&ul=en&_u=.oK29L&ds=app&sr=640x1136&v=1&_s=65&_crc=0&an=App+Name&_v=mi3.1.2&ht=1432174659618&qt=5020&z=1540606593628258960
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:226): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:529): hit(s) Successfully deleted
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:237): 1 hit(s) sent
```

**The HTTP Status is -1.** And Google Analytics doesn't get this hit.
I have tried to send this request through Web Browser, it get HTTP Status 200. And Google Analytics got this hit.

## So, how to sent Hit(s) to GA when we are using GET to request https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect...........?

Comment: Bob, how did you fix this error! I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Sana Sorry, we don't have enough time to fight with this problem. We just suspended it. We expecting some day Google Analytic can make every thing as simple as Flurry.

Comment: @RobertYiJiang Any update on this issue ?. Even I am facing the same issue