# Google Analytics HTTP status

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, google-analytics

I implement Google Analytics but it is not working good.

I think is there wrong with "`Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1`"

Why status is -1 & hits not seen?

Help me to solve this...

Comment: I think your are downvoted because you do not say what you are actually doing, just that whatever it is does not work.  Maybe you can give some insight into the code you are using, that might make the question answerable.

Comment: Possible dup here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363622/google-analytics-http-status-1-when-sending-hits-by-request-get-https-ssl-g  ... but sadly no real answer there either. I'm facing this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work
use this in app delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
//Google Analytics Code

// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

// Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

// Initialize tracker. Replace with your tracking ID.
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXXXXXX-X"];

id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker=tracker;
}
```